# Sms ContentObserver onChange() fires multiple times

Tags: java, android, contentobserver

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but nobody has been able to come up with a working answer from what I have seen.

Im working on an app to intercept text messages and depending on the sending #, pop up with a custom alert. I have it working beautifully with a broadcast receiver, however if the user has goSms installed the `onReceive()` method is never called as goSms aborts it before it ever reaches my app.

To get around this, Im trying a content observer on `content://sms/`
Its working just fine, however the `onChange()` is called twice, with exactly the same parameters. Ive tried to check the time stamps, but they are the same, as is the type and every other parameter I have set.

From what I've seen, this is a common issue, but not one that I've seen answered anywhere.

```
    @Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    super.onChange(selfChange);
    querySMS();
}

protected void querySMS() {
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(u, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToNext(); // this will make it point to the first record, which is the last SMS sent
    String type = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("type"));
    String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body")); //content of sms
    String add = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")); //phone num
    if (type.equals("1")) {
        if (add.equals(Test.SENDER)) {              
            String[] bodys = body.split(" ", 7);
            if (bodys[0].equals("test")) {
                test = true;
            }
            cat = bodys[1];
            level = bodys[2];
            urgency = bodys[3];
            certainty = bodys[4];
            carrier = bodys[5];
            message = bodys[6];
            final Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlertActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("title", cat);
            b.putString("certainty", certainty);
            b.putString("urgency", urgency);
            b.putString("level", level);
            b.putString("message", message);
            b.putBoolean("test", test);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
            if (carrierName.replaceAll(" ", "").equals(carrier)) {

                context.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                //testing
                Toast.makeText(context, carrierName.replaceAll(" ", ""), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because of the `onChange()` being fired twice, Im getting two alerts as well. I cannot for the life of me figure out a way around this.

Comment: links to the other (incomplete) answers would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the two are identical:
store each message recv'd 
compare it to previous messages recv'd
if not found, process
if found, discard the message

The life of the messages stored should be infinitesimal, a little circular buffer of 5 messages should be fine.

Comment: the message is only being received once though. its not coming in twice. tbh, i dont even know what the second `onChange` is even being triggered from.

Comment: Ah. coupled you idea with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012703/android-detect-sms-outgoing-incorrect-count and I got it working. I think I misunderstood what you meant the first time I read over it. I created a static `arrayList` and used this to check.           `if (!ids.contains(id)) { ids.add(id);context.startActivity(intent);}`

Answer (score 4):

here is my code, it works fine for me

```
public class SmsObserver extends ContentObserver {  
    private Context context;
    private static int initialPos;
    private static final String TAG = "SMSContentObserver";
    private static final Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");

    public SmsObserver(Handler handler, Context ctx) {
        super(handler);
        context = ctx;
        initialPos = getLastMsgId();

    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        queryLastSentSMS();
    }

    public int getLastMsgId() {

        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        int lastMsgId = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        Log.i(TAG, "Last sent message id: " + String.valueOf(lastMsgId));
        return lastMsgId;
    }

    protected void queryLastSentSMS() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Cursor cur =
                    context.getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);

                if (cur.moveToNext()) {


                    try {
                        if (initialPos != getLastMsgId()) {
                            // Here you get the last sms. Do what you want.
                            String receiver = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
                           System.out.println(" Receiver Ph no :"+receiver);


                            // Then, set initialPos to the current position.
                            initialPos = getLastMsgId(); 
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Treat exception here
                    }
                }
                cur.close();
            }
        }).start();

    }

}//End of class SmsObserver
```

Answer (score 3):

You can save last message's id and compare it to the id of the message that is returned by `cur` in `onChange`. you then can simply disregard the message if ids are the same.

```
// might contain mistakes, but you'll get the idea:
protected void querySMS() {
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(u, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToNext(); 
    if (lastId == cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex("_id")))
        return;
    lastId = cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    ... //continue as it was
}
```

However - GO SMS only prevents other app's from recieving Broadcast if the user selected this option (*Recieve Settings - Disable other message notification*) - so if the user does not want other apps to disturb him - I think it's good idea not to do so.

Comment: The app Im working on isnt one that should be ignored, ever. Its to come preinstalled on devices and take total precedence over anything else currently running on the phone. I did something similiar to this, if you look in the comments of the answer below you can see.

Comment: you do understand that the snippet you've posted should go really, really long way before it can be used in app that is to come preintalled, don't you?

Comment: oh yes of course. ive only just started the project. its got a long way to go

Answer (score 0):

I just use SharedPreference to remark last SMS info (like: `id\type` ...). if it is the same, I will `return`.